# How to implement movement and placing of UITableViewCells in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing an application in which I need to achieve movement and placement of UITableViewCells by dragging them to the desired positions(just like as we do for icons by long pressing them and placing them to the desired place). How to achieve it for the table view cells?  Code for this is appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

See and follow the instructions in [Managing the Reordering of Rows](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html) in the Table View Programming Guide for iOS.

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I am not able to rearrange the rows with that code(where you have given the link) Can you provide me the code??

Comment: How am I supposed to know how the specific code for your app must look? You have to adapt the code from the documentation to your concrete case.

Comment: . Finally I am able to rearrange the rows. Now one more problem I am facing.I am rearranging grouped table view(5 sections with 1 row each).When I rearrange one section its joining with one more section but I want intact i,e 5 sections with 1 row each even after rearrangement.How to that?